# Is there a way to generate audio/sound of different frequencies using react native

Tags: react-native

I have been searching for any library of react native which supports generating audio tone ( sine ) of provided frequencies and amplitude. The inputs which i have are frequency and amplitude. As i am a newbie to react-native, it would be really helpful if somebody could share some idea on how to implement this. Thanks .

Comment: Generally, [questions asking for recommendations for software library are considered off-topic for the site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  You might have better luck at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: React Native is a UI framework. Why do you think it has anything to do with audio tones?